# Remove Unity safely on Ubuntu 16.0

Tags: 16.04, unity, lxde

I have installed LXDE on Ubuntu 16.0 and want to remove Unity in a safely way without other programs crashing.

I found those ones :

[How can you remove Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity/475908#475908)

[Remove Unity completely and exchange it with LXDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606089/remove-unity-completely-and-exchange-it-with-lxde)

It's unclear if other programs will not crash after removing unity.

Comment: If this is a fresh installation, you can just start with Lubuntu.

Comment: I agree with @edwinksl. Removing something like Unity isn't a trivial task especially if you're new to Linux.

Comment: Removing Unity or **any other DE** isn't a trivial task even if you're experienced. Case in point, I know enough NOT to do certain things but still I'm unable to properly help this person: https://askubuntu.com/questions/945395/uninstalling-deepin-de-from-ubuntu